# Ory Network - Get Identity via OAuth2 flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, ory

Bottom line: How do I use a `ory_at_*` token to get the identity backing that user when using ORY Network

Context: I'm trying to set up a ORY Network setup that can be used as an IdP for a custom social SSO connection in Auth0.

I have identities storied in ORY (which I guess is Kratos?). I've configured a custom "social connection" in Auth0 successfully, insofar as I can see the login prompt, accept it, etc.

Now I'd like to be able to fetch data from ORY both in Auth0 and in my app.

Auth0's custom sso connections give me an access token that looks like `ory_at_...` which per the ORY **Hydra** docs means its a Hydra access token. That makes sense to me. But now I want to go from that access token to be able to hit the `/sessions/whoami` endpoint, but that requires a `session_token`.

This must be a pretty normal thing for people to do?